# Convert and map/add Entity Framework Data to user defined class

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-6

```js
List < Special > spl = new List < Special > ();
DBEntities entity = new DBEntities();
DateTime ? startDate = Convert.ToDateTime("2017-01-01");
DateTime ? end = Convert.ToDateTime("2017-04-18");
IEnumerable < Object > splist = entity.spGetData(startDate, end, "AAA").ToList();

public class Special {
  public int ? NO {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string[] SNo {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string[] Div {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public string[] ITEMO {
    get;
    set;
  }
  public DateTime ? DDT {
    get;
    set;
  }

}
```

I have a stored procedure which is returning some records set which I am accessing through entity framework. but the return type is **system.data.entity.core.objects.objectresult** and I want to map/add it to my user defined class. It says something this **Unable to cast object of type.....** **I converted it to IEnumerable List but I want to iterate through each record and make my own custom selected objects list and pull the data inside Special class object.**

Comment: Please read [mcve] for better help.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with javascript or angular code. Please tag questions appropriately

Comment: Can you provide the code for your stored procedure as well? Without knowing the structure of the data being returned there's no way to know whether or not your class/object will properly map it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there a reason you can't just use the ObjectResult class that Entity generates automatically, as opposed to creating your own class? If what you're doing makes sense, one option (supposing that the result set isn't too large) would be to transform the results of the stored procedure with the Select method that Linq provides. It would look something like this:

```
MyClass myObject = storedProcedure().Select( s => new MyClass() { 

myVariable = s.variable,
myOtherVariable = s.otherVariable,
// and so on for each property that you want to map to your class

});
```

Comment: Good one @Matt. While the answer maybe/is correct, the OP does not provide enough info in the question about the issue.. make sure you check for question edits and reflect the answer.

Comment: **Matt**, Is there any one go to assign a set of records to my user defined class by converting the result set return by sp successfully.

Comment: **Matt**, Can you please check and let me know the code.

Comment: @Saleem, the answer @Matt provided is correct in your case. Instead of `IEnumerable<Object>` use `IEnumerable<Special>` and after `toList()` perform the conversion as provided in the answer. `MyClass` becomes `Special`.

Comment: I tried this, but no luck. ***List<Special> myObject = (List<Special>)gfientity.spGetProductLinePerformance(startDate, end, "AAA").ToList().Select(s => new List<Special>()
            {
                //s.NO says Cannot convert string to Special
                //simply returns error. "Unable to Cast object....."

            });**

Comment: Can you guide me how to create list of special and store the result return by stored procedure. Thanks

Comment: List<Special> myObject = gfientity.spGetProductLine(....).Select(s => new Special() { assign whatever variables from the stored procedure results that you want in your Special object (see above) }.ToList();